# When inserting into a Linked List, why can't I just point the head to the inserted value?

Tags: data-structures, linked-list

I'm trying to work with Linked Lists insertion and I understand most of it, but I am reading a lot of examples online and there's one thing I'm seeing all of them do but I don't particularly understand why, see below (apologies for if/elif being out of order):

```
    # Below I understand. Point to the head and point the head to the new value
    elif self.head.data >= new_node.data:
         new_node.next = self.head
         self.head = new_node


     # This I don't, why can't I just say self.head = new_node? 
     if self.head is None:
         new_node.next = self.head
         self.head = new_node
```

Answer (score 1):

They're doing that assignment to make sure that `new_node.next` is a known value. If it's allocated memory that wasn't initialized, then there could be any garbage in `new_node.next`. So if then you tried to follow the list, when you got to that node, you might try to dereference an invalid pointer. By setting it to `self.head`, which is known to be `None`, you avoid that potential problem.

Assigning `new_node.next = None` would do the same thing.